# Show that there are infinitely many values of n for which $23| n^2 + 14n + 47$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Show that there are infinitely many values of n for which $23| n^2 + 14n + 47$

So far I have shown that there is in fact some solution.

By the definition of division,
$n^2 + 14n +47 = 23k$

Thus,

$n^2+14n+49 = 23k +2$

$(n+7)^2 = 23k + 2$

$(n+7)^2 \equiv 2  (mod 23) $

Since 23 is a prime p s.t. $p \equiv 1 or 7 (mod 8)$, thus there is some solution for this congruence.

Is this the right way to go about this? Any advice on how to move forward?

Comment: It's the right way. Now, if $23\mid n^2 + 14 n + 47$, what about $n+23$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(\pm 5)^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{23}$. Hence, $n+7 \equiv \pm 5 \pmod{23}$ provides one class of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You're just there.

Since this congruence *has* a solution (e.g. $n=-2$), it has an *infinite number* of solutions, e.g. $n=-2+23k$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$ (since $n\equiv m \implies (n+7)^2\equiv (m+7)^2$ mod any).

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to consider the formulation $n^2-9n+1=0(mod 23)$. There are two families of solutions: -2 + 23k and 11 + 23k.